# Nested python loop revisited

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, nested, vectorization

I know there are already several posts about how to speed up a nested python loop, but I wasn't able to apply those to my problem.
I have a nested python for loop, the first one iterating over all elements of a list, the second one iterating over all remaining list items, yielding a combination of all list items with each other. For one I think this is rather ugly, but also it is really slow. Any ideas how to make this faster and more pythonic?

```
n = len(delta_vec)
for j in range(0, n - 1, 1):
    for k in range(j + 1, n, 1):
        w = 1. / np.exp((mjd_list[k] - mjd_list[j]) / avg_time)
        w_sum = w_sum + w
        P = delta_vec[j] * delta_vec[k]
        j_index = j_index + w * np.sign(P) * np.sqrt(np.abs(P))
```

Comment: Could you add a quick explanation of what other posts you reviewed and why those solutions didn't work?  This will help prevent you getting answers which aren't going to solve your problem

Comment: Not a complete answer but some tips: iterating with enumerate() instead of range() is more pythonic and could improve performance a bit as enumerate yields it's result. Also if performance is critical you could rewrite your function as a list in comprehension: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sure the fastest way would be to not use any for-loops in Python or generators from `itertools`, but to use vectorized math from `Numpy`, something like this:

```
n = len(delta_vec)
jj, kk = np.triu_indices(n, 1)
ww = 1. / np.exp((mjd_list[kk] - mjd_list[jj]) / avg_time)
w_sum = np.sum(ww)
PP = delta_vec[jj] * delta_vec[kk]
j_index = np.sum(ww * np.sign(PP) * np.sqrt(np.abs(PP)))
```

where all variables with double letters are vectors of length `n`. Note that you would have to convert your lists to numpy-arrays for this to work. You might even gain a bit more speed by replacing `1. / exp((a - b) / c)` by `exp((b - a) / c)`.

Explanation: you are doing calculation with all pairs of indices up to `n`, without taking pairs with the same indices (so no 1,1) and where the first in the pair is always the smallest number (so no 2,1). If you would make a 2-D matrix of all the possible pairs, you see that you are doing your computation only over elements above the diagonal, so you can use the function [np.triu_index](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html). To show that this works, your loop generates these indices:

```
In [18]: n = 4
    ...: for j in range(0, n - 1, 1):
    ...:     for k in range(j + 1, n, 1):
    ...:         print j, k
0 1
0 2
0 3
1 2
1 3
2 3
```

You can generate exactly the same indices with `triu_indices`:

```
In [19]: np.triu_indices(n, 1)
Out[19]: (array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3]))
```

Quick test for correctness and speed:

```
import numpy as np
# generate some fake data
n = 300
mjd_vec = np.random.rand(n)
delta_vec = np.random.rand(n)
mjd_list = list(mjd_vec)
delta_list = list(delta_vec)
avg_time = 123

def f1():
    w_sum = j_index = 0
    n = len(delta_list)
    for j in range(0, n - 1, 1):
        for k in range(j + 1, n, 1):
            w = 1. / np.exp((mjd_list[k] - mjd_list[j]) / avg_time)
            w_sum = w_sum + w
            P = delta_vec[j] * delta_vec[k]
            j_index = j_index + w * np.sign(P) * np.sqrt(np.abs(P))
    return w_sum, j_index

def f2():
    n = len(delta_vec)
    jj, kk = np.triu_indices(n, 1)
    ww = 1. / np.exp((mjd_vec[kk] - mjd_vec[jj]) / avg_time)
    w_sum = np.sum(ww)
    PP = delta_vec[jj] * delta_vec[kk]
    j_index = np.sum(ww * np.sign(PP) * np.sqrt(np.abs(PP)))
    return w_sum, j_index
```

Result:

```
In [3]: f1()
Out[3]: (44839.864280781003, 18985.189058689775)

In [4]: f2()
Out[4]: (44839.864280781003, 18985.189058689775)

In [5]: timeit f1()
1 loops, best of 3: 629 ms per loop

In [6]: timeit f2()
100 loops, best of 3: 7.88 ms per loop
```

So the numpy version produces the same result and is **a factor 80 faster**!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're iterating over two lists simultaneously, taking the items from the same indices in each list, and dealing with all pairs of indices. In that case, something like:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations, izip
>>> for x, y in combinations(izip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]), 2):
    print zip(x, y)


[(1, 2), (4, 5)]
[(1, 3), (4, 6)]
[(2, 3), (5, 6)]
```

Each output list here contains a two-tuple of the pair from the first list, then a two-tuple of the pair from the second list. Using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) allows this without having to build a whole list (except the inner `zip`).

Using your own variable names, if you iterated over:

```
for d_v, m_l in combinations(izip(delta_vec, mjd_list)):
```

then `zip(d_v, m_l)` would give you the equivalent of:

```
[(delta_vec[j], delta_vec[k]), (mjd_list[j], mjd_list[k])]
```

in your current approach

Alternatively, as you're using `numpy`, there is no doubt some blazingly-fast array-based approach I don't know about.

Comment: +1 Just wanted to suggest `combinations` as well, but using it with `izip` is even better. However, you should explain how exactly this is applied to the calculation, as it requires quite some adjustments in the code.

Comment: To be honest, the more I look at it the more I doubt that `izip` and then zipping it back really makes it simpler than just iterating the combinations of the indices... Guess you could do something like `for (dj, dk), (mj, mk) in combinations(...)` though.

Comment: @tobias_k the `izip` is to get the pairs from the two lists, the `zip` is to put the combinations back into the sensible order (i.e. not `[(dj, mj), (dk, mk)]`).

Answer (score 0):

I would make two changes:

1. Change the iteration
2. Move the computation code to a function

This will help clean up your code and make it a little more "pythonic."  As for the, the bottleneck is just hat you have a lot of calculations to do.  Python isn't designed to be fast, so if the speed is really an issue, consider outsourcing the calculation to another code which is faster.  Typically the compiled codes (the C family, FORTRAN, etc) are pretty good for stuff like this.

```
def computations(x, y, i, j):
    w = 1. / np.exp((mjd_list[i] - mjd_list[j]) / avg_time)
    w_sum = w_sum + w
    P = x * y
    j_index = j_index + w * np.sign(P) * np.sqrt(np.abs(P))

    return [stuff you want to keep]

for i, x in enumerate(delta_vec):
    for j, y in delta_vec[i:]:
         result = computations(x, y, i, j)
```

Comment: This won't work. 1) x is the index and i is the element; 2) you also need the index for y; 3) the method still expects indices as input, but you are passing it the elements (well, one index and one element), and 4) I doubt that this is faster, slicing a new sublist in each iteration...

Comment: @tobias_k, I wasn't really going for faster, just prettier, I'll update to make the changes, thanks for pointing them out

Comment: Some issues: 1) The code in the question iterates over two lists in parallel (`mjd_list` and `delta_vec1`). In this case, I find it more pythonic/clear to do explicit indexing with `j` and `k` than your 'asymmetric solution' which uses `enumerate` on one list, and indexing on the other. Using `zip` might look better. 2) The outer loop should skip the last element: `for i, x in enumerate(delta_vec[:-1])`. 3) No need to go to Fortran to speed things up considerably, see my answer. 4) As Tobias said, you are making a copy of a slice of `delta_vec` on every iteration, this is slow.